# Perlin noise always produces the same map. How do I generate a different map?

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, tilemap, perlin-noise

My tile map takes a spritesheet, slices the tiles up based on a resolution, and assigns each tile to an array, which uses an integer. Since perlin noise generates a float between 0 and 1, I multiply the float by the number of tiles I want to use for terrain generation, round (perlin*tileNum) to a whole number, and then use the whole number integer as the number for the color of the tile.

The code I have to make terrain *works*, but I noticed that no matter the number that `scale` is, it basically generates the same terrain, and just stretches it based off of `scale` to fit the tile map. They essentially are all the same terrain, which is what I don't want.

Here are [pictures of what's happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ai4iN.jpg), as well as [a pastebin](https://pastebin.com/ZPNEirB2) of my tile map engine. I apologize if my wording of the problem is difficult to understand.

What would I need to do to make each generated landscape different? I know I need to reevaluate the Perlin Noise aspect, but I don't know exactly what to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is add an offset to your noise lookups.

Effectively, treat (0, 0) like it's (123.4, 987.6) or some other arbitrary shift.

This centers a different part of the noise domain and you'll get different results.

If using multiple octaves of noise, you can even play with different offsets per octave to mix it up further, so it's no longer a simple translation of the whole noise domain.